Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mailtrap.io, port: 25;
I'm trying to send mail through Java implementation but some how it's not working as expected. Using below implementation to send mail:
package application;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            

            Properties props = new Properties();
//          props.put("mail.smtp.user", "blabla@gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // Enable authentication if needed
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // Enable TLS encryption
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","*");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
            // Get mail session
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

            try {
              // Create MimeMessage object
              MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

              // Set sender address
              email.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@localserver.com"));

              // Set recipient address
              email.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("mygmail@gmail.com"));

              // Set subject
              email.setSubject("code verification");

              // Set message content (text/plain)
              email.setContent("this is you code " + Math.random()*100, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

              // Send the email
              System.out.println("lllllll");
              Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
              transport.connect("sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io", "mygmail@gmail.com", "mypassword"); // Connect to SMTP server
              transport.sendMessage(email, email.getAllRecipients()); // Send email
              transport.close();

              System.out.println("Email sent successfully!");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}


Got the following error:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mailtrap.io, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at application.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:40)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:686)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
    ... 7 more

I'm able to send email using SMTP in Python and JavaScript. I have tested this implementation in Windows 10 and 11 as well. I have also opened PORT 25 for both my local system and internet provider. Also tried with PORT 2525 but problem still persist. Only difference I noticed with PORT 25, it's taking some time to process and return an error.
Below is error stackTrace
lllllll
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at application.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:45)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:686)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
    ... 4 more



Reading through their documentation, use port 587 and live.smtp.mailtrap.io
